# Unable to access http://localhost:3838/Rshiny/ for Rshiny application outside ubuntu

Tags: r, shiny, localhost, ubuntu-14.04

I able to access my rshiny application inside ubuntu hosted in shiny server.
How can I access it outside ubuntu.

I want a simple link. example: https:my-shiny/app/ to access my rshiny app by any one over the internet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/

Comment: You can either use `ShinyApps.io` or `RStudioConnect.io` that will help you share shiny applications or interactive documents over the internet.